# How to do a power analysis for an unbalanced mixed effects ANOVA?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, statistical-power, unbalanced-classes

I need suggestions for how to calculate the $n$ required for 80% and 90% power for >30% change from baseline ($T_0$) at $T_1$ or $T_2$, drug vs. placebo, 2:1 ratio; 20% CV in test; factors: subject, treatment, time, and two Gaussian covariates: one of the covariates is the baseline measurement of the endpoint. Please let me know if additional information is required for this calculation.

It would also be really helpful if someone could provide a proper statistical description of this study design.

I'm just a biologist and not a statistician, so where possible, please use lay terms.

Added question: Is there a way to do this with G*Power?

Comment: If you can figure out how to *simulate* data with the properties you describe then you can do a tailored power analysis by just repeatedly simulating and running whatever analysis you expect to do for each data set and aggregating the outcomes.  More of a programming problem really...

Comment: Thanks for the useful suggestion. I'm afraid that kind of programming is beyond me, but if I don't find another solution to the problem, I will look for someone who can help me with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a way to solution not a definitive answer: The paper below could give some direction to this kind of design:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4394709/

The supplementary material show power calculations examples for t tests and regressions in R. Since regressions and Anovas are the same thing in principle, I believe that this a very fruitful start.

Answer (score 1):

A pragmatic choice is to take the smaller of the two treatment groups as the $n$ of both groups. This gives you a conservative measure of power. In G*Power you would just use the default proportion test sample size calculation.